# Neglect higher order derivatives in expression

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, replacement

Say I have an expression of this sort:

```
Derivative[5][x1][t]+Derivative[3][x2][t]+x1[t]+Derivative[2][x1][t]
```

and so on...

I would like to ask Mathematica to neglext all expressions having derivatives higher than a given order (say N).

What would be a good solution for that?

Comment: Related: https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/192076/linearity-assumption

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Derivative[5][x1][t] + Derivative[3][x2][t] + x1[t] + 
  Derivative[2][x1][t] /. Derivative[k_][x_][t_] /; k >= 3 :> 0
```

> x1[t] + (x1^[Prime][Prime])[t]

For understanding `/;` see the documentation of `Condition`.