# Linearity Assumption

Tags: calculus-and-analysis, assumptions

I'd like to define a set of variables of this sort:

```
{K1[t],K2[t],...}
```

Adding a general assumption: all such variables are linear. 
I'd like to do this to avoid Mathematica having to show me higher order derivatives of these functions in my solution.

Comment: I think the questions are different. In this case I've been asking "assumptions". In question you mentioned above, I was asking a "truncation".

Answer (score 12, accepted):

```
K1 /: Derivative[k_][K1] /; k >= 2 := (0 &)
```